# Capture all questions from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I have been trying to use Javascript's RegEx to parse out every question from a given paragraph. However, I am getting unwanted results:

**Javascript**

```
regex = /(\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)/g;
result = regex.exec("I can see you. Where are you? I am here! How did you get there?");
```

**Expected result**

```
["Where are you?", "How did you get there?"]
```

**Actual result**

```
["I can see you.", "I can see you."]
```

*PS: If there is a better way of doing this, I'm all ears!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = string.match(/\(?[A-Z][^\.!\?]+[!\.\?]\)?/g);
x.filter(function(sentence) {
  return sentence.indexOf('?') >= 0;
})
```

Comment: You're welcome, any reason you switched answers?  Functionally the same afaik, though the newer one is a bit shorter regex.

Comment: Your filter combined with the shorter regex is what I found to be the best method. I wish I could pick both as the best :)

Comment: No worries thanks, just making sure I didn't miss some subtle issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `.exec` method of the JavaScript regex option only returns the first match with captures. It also updates the regex Object with the position in the string of the match. This is what allows you to loop through a string using the `.exec` method (and why you're only getting the first match).

Try using the `.match` method of the String object instead:

```
regex = /(\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)/g;
result = ("I can see you. Where are you? I am here! How did you get there?").match(regex);
```

This gives the expected result of:

```
[
    "I can see you.",
    "Where are you?",
    "I am here!",
    "How did you get there?"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = / ?([^.!]*)\?/g;
text = "I can see you. Where are you? I am here! How did you get there?";
result = [];
while (m = regex.exec(text)) {
  result.push(m[1])
}
```

The output:

```
[ 'Where are you?',
  'How did you get there?' ]
```